# Drools 6.1.0.Final Runtime jars

Tags: dependencies, drools, jbpm

I am using the Drools 6.1.0.Final documentation to set up my Eclipse environment.
I am referring this documentation:

`Section "1.3.1.4.4. Drools Runtimes"` in "http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.1.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/"

Out of the many binaries in my drools installation (unzipped the "drools-distribution-6.1.0.Final.zip")

```
D:\Drools-6.1.0.Final\binaries
```

*Which jars constitute the Drools runtime jar file?*

I could just point my eclipse to the drools binaries folder, but I wanted to understand the minimal set of runtime jar files needed by Eclipse.

`Section Section "1.3.1.1. Dependencies and JARs"` does talk about the dependency jars such as :

```
knowledge-api.jar
knowledge-internal-api.jar
drools-core.jar
drools-compiler.jar
drools-jsr94.jar
drools-decisiontables.jar
```

I was able to locate these 4:

```
drools-core.jar
drools-compiler.jar
drools-jsr94.jar
drools-decisiontables.jar
```

However these 2 :

```
knowledge-api.jar
knowledge-internal-api.jar
```

Is this substitution correct in Drools 6.1.0.Final release

```
knowledge-api.jar --> kie-api-6.1.0.Final.jar
knowledge-internal-api.jar --> kie-internal-6.1.0.Final.jar
```

What other jars I will need out of the Drools distribution's binaries folder to create a complete Drools Runtime?

Comment: Are you not using Maven/Gradle? Just take a look at the dependencies defined by org.drools:drools-core. You may or may not also need org.drools:drools-compiler.

Comment: @Steve as I mentioned; I am following the documentation mentioned in my post.

Comment: Not relevant to the question. Assuming that you're not using Maven for your build, you can see the dependencies here: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer to your question as it depends on the Drools features actually used by your application. If it uses templates, you'll need drools-templates-*.jar. If you load a precompiled knowledge base, you may not need drools-compiler-*.jar and the antlr jar.

You shouldn't be needing the drools-jsr94.jar unless you're using this weak (but generic) API.

It also varies with Drools version. 6 has renamed some, and some reordering has taken place in some 5.x version (I think).

What I do is to run my Java application, starting it from the command line using a shell script where I define the class path, e.g. (note that this is truncated - it's a single string, on one line):

```
export CLASSPATH=".:$root/drools-core-${tag}.jar:$root/kie-api-${tag}.jar:...
    :$root/kie-internal-${tag}.jar."
```

Now if the Java compiler doesn't find a class, I hunt for it in the jars, and add that. Clumsy? Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering to use a maven. Add this in your pom.xml it can manage your dependncies.

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>7.15.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```